# make a variable last for a call stack

Tags: c#, recursion, concurrency, callstack

I have a class that contains some fields. I need to compare instances of this class by value, so I defined `GetHashCode` and `Equals` accordingly. Because the class allows circular references, I need a mechanism to avoid infinite recursion (for a more detailed explanation see [Value-equals and circular references: how to resolve infinite recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586427/value-equals-and-circular-references-how-to-resolve-infinite-recursion)). I solved this problem by modifying my `Equals` method so that it keeps track of the comparisons done before:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Foo Reference { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() { return Name.GetHashCode(); }

    static HashSet<(Foo,Foo)> checkedPairs
        = new HashSet<(Foo,Foo)>(ValuePairRefEqualityComparer<Foo>.Instance);
        // using an equality comparer that compares corresponding items for reference;
        // implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46589154/5333340

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo other = obj as Foo;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        if !(Name.Equals(other.Name))
            return false;

        if (checkedPairs.Contains((this,other)) || checkedPairs.Contains((other,this)))
            return true;

        checkedPairs.Add((this,other));

        bool refsEqual = Reference.Equals(other.Reference);
        checkedPairs.Clear();
        return refsEqual;
    }
}
```

Imagine the following code in the main method:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo { Name = "foo" };
Foo foo2 = new Foo { Name = "foo" };
foo1.Reference = foo2;
foo2.Reference = foo1;

bool foo_equals_bar = foo1.Equals(foo2);
Console.WriteLine("foo_equals_bar = " + foo_equals_bar);
```

`foo1.Equals(foo2)` will store `(foo1,foo2)` in `checkedPairs` before it calls `foo2.Equals(foo1)`. Inside `foo2.Equals(foo1)` it will be noticed that `checkedPairs` contains `(foo1,foo2)`, and `true` will be returned. This result is transferred to the `equal` variable inside the call of `foo1.Equals(foo2)`, then `checkedPairs` is cleared, and `true` is finally returned to the main method.

(Without utilizing `checkedPairs` inside `Equals`, there would be an infinite recursion jumping between `foo1.Equals(foo2)` and `foo2.Equals(foo1)`.)

This works allright in my single-threaded, non-concurrent sandbox environment. However, **I am only using a `static` field for `checkedPairs` because I don't know any other way to transfer the already collected items from one call of `Equals` to the next inside a call stack.**

But with this approach I cannot use a multi-threaded or concurrent environment, where several `Equals` checks might run in parallel or in a mixed-up order (e.g. due to passing `Equals` as a delegate and invoking it later on instead of immediately).

Questions:

1. Will using a thread-static variable work? I am afraid not, because I can imagine that different `Equals` calls from the same call stack could still be executed on different threads (but I don't know).
2. Is there a way to make `checkedPairs` "call stack static"? So that each call stack gets its own copy of `checkedPairs`? Then for each new call stack, a new (empty) `checkedPairs` would be created, filled during recursion, and garbage collected after the recursion ends.

Comment: I usually just add a parameter to the Equal() method to pass items.  There is no reason Equals has to have one parameter. If you have a class with ICompare make the Equal(object) call MyEqual() with two parameters to do the recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks jdweng to point me to an easy solution that works for the particular code stated in the question:

Remove the `checkedPairs` field from the `Foo` class and replace the `Equals` method by this code:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return MyEquals(obj, new HashSet<(Foo,Foo)>(ValuePairRefEqualityComparer<Foo>.Instance));
}

private bool MyEquals(object obj, HashSet<(Foo,Foo)> checkedPairs)
{
    Foo other = obj as Foo;
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    if (!Name.Equals(other.Name))
        return false;

    if (checkedPairs.Contains((this,other)) || checkedPairs.Contains((other,this)))
        return true;

    checkedPairs.Add((this,other));

    return Reference.MyEquals(other.Reference, checkedItems);
}
```

**However, this approach is not going to work in general**. Take for example the classes from this question: [Value-equals and circular references: how to resolve infinite recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586427/value-equals-and-circular-references-how-to-resolve-infinite-recursion), and imagine I defined `MyEquals` analogously there for both `Club` and `Person`. Since `MyEquals` cannot be called from outside the class (I want it private), there will still be infinite recursion. E.g. when `Person.MyEquals` is called, it will call `FavouriteInstitution.Equals` inside, but it should redirect to `FavouriteInstitution.MyEquals` somehow(with a possibly already filled `checkedPairs`!). Also, `Members.SetEquals(other.Members)` will redirect to `Person.Equals` instead of `Person.MyEquals`.

Comment: If you do `foo1.Reference = null; foo2.Reference = null;` then `foo1.Equals(foo2);`, `foo1.Equals(foo1);` or `foo2.Equals(foo2);` all will throw null reference exceptions.